# PHP/HTML/CSS/FileMaker PHP API Conditional Formatting <td>

Tags: php, html, css, filemaker

I'm fairly new to PHP and I only am using it because I need to publish some of my FileMaker database on the web.

What I would like to do is have a  cell in a table to change colors based on a field in my FileMaker database called "ReferralStatus" which will only ever have a value of "Red", "Green" or "Yellow"

How would I go about accomplishing this with PHP/HTML/CSS ? I was thinking use an if/else conditional to check the status and assign a class but how would I apply that to the  element?

Right now I am using a foreach loop to generate the table row and table data columns.

The code below worked for me:

```
    <?php 
    foreach($relatedRecords as $related_record) {
    echo 
    '<tr>' . 
    '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; background: #cacaca;">' . $related_record->getField('ReferredLeadsToCustomerLogins::DateReceived') . '</td>' . 
    '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; background: #cacaca;">' . $related_record->getField('ReferredLeadsToCustomerLogins::FirstName') . '</td>' . 
    '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; background: #cacaca;">' . $related_record->getField('ReferredLeadsToCustomerLogins::LastName') . '</td>' . 
    '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; background: #cacaca;">' . $related_record->getField('ReferredLeadsToCustomerLogins::FullAddress') . '</td>' . 
    '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; background-color: '. $related_record->getField('ReferredLeadsToCustomerLogins::ReferralStatus') . ';">' . $related_record->getField('ReferredLeadsToCustomerLogins::ReferralStatus') . '</td>' .
    '</tr>';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Please be sure you provide code you've tried in your questions so that we can see your thought process!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML/PHP:

```
        <?php 
        foreach($relatedRecords as $related_record) {
        echo 
        '<tr>' . 
        '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; background: #cacaca;">' . $related_record->getField('ReferredLeadsToCustomerLogins::DateReceived') . '</td>' . 
        '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; background: #cacaca;">' . $related_record->getField('ReferredLeadsToCustomerLogins::FirstName') . '</td>' . 
        '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; background: #cacaca;">' . $related_record->getField('ReferredLeadsToCustomerLogins::LastName') . '</td>' . 
        '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; background: #cacaca;">' . $related_record->getField('ReferredLeadsToCustomerLogins::FullAddress') . '</td>' . 
        '<td style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px; background-color: '. $related_record->getField('ReferredLeadsToCustomerLogins::ReferralStatus') . ';">' . $related_record->getField('ReferredLeadsToCustomerLogins::ReferralStatus') . '</td>' .
        '</tr>';
        } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP/HTML:

```
<td class="<?php echo $ReferralStatus; ?>"> foo </td>
```

$ReferralStatus is one of "Green", "Red" or "Yellow", so that the line will output sth like this:

```
<td class="Red"> foo </td>
```

CSS:

```
.Red {
  background-color: red;
}
.Green {
  background-color: green;
}
.Yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me, it didn't take the class but when I changed class to style and just did the background-color property it worked fine, so no biggie but yeah not sure why my class didn't take.

Comment: Maybe case-sensitivity? Check what actually got output. Some unexpected value of the $Referral variable?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't even work when I apply a class to it manually without using a variable. I had to style each individual item inline.

Comment: Well, if you renamed the variable to your actual variable, it should work.